# Options Menu shows slowly

Tags: android, menu

In my Android Application I want to have a options menu in the toolbar and the functionality works just fine. However it takes a considerably long time (about one second) until the menu show after the 3 dots in the toolbar are pressed.

At first i thought, that it might be some problem specific to my app, but I created a new project from the Android Studio template and the problem still persists. (Though it feels a little bit faster than in my application)

The menu is created as documented in the docs:

### menu.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/manageBTConnection"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_white"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/connect"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/backgroundService"
        android:title="Start background service" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/sendToBackend"
        android:title="Send to Backend" />

</menu>
```

### MainActivity

```java
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }
```

Compared to other Android apps it takes a lot longer than usual and feels clunky.

Is there any way to speed up the creation/showing of the dropdown menu?

Many thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. So slow! Activity launches without any option menu and then later it appears suddenly. Option menus should be visible right when activity is launched. Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Were you using NavigationComponent with the toolbar?

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same thing. Here I've profiled what happens when I tap to open the menu. Notice that it takes 900 to 1000 milliseconds for the menu to appear.

[image]